# jQTouch and dynamic php/mysql list linking to inside anchor and pass on a php/mysql variable

Tags: php, mysql, list, dynamic, jqtouch

I'm working on a full screen web app for the iPhone/iPod, using the latest jQTouch.

On the first "page" (as in ) a list is generated from a mysql database. Every item of that list should be a link to another "page" and pass on a variable that is unique to that item (so that the next "page" knows which item was clicked on). For now I have this:

```
<ul class="rounded plastic">
    <?php
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempCursist WHERE achternaam BETWEEN 'a%' AND 'e%' ORDER BY achternaam, voorletters");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) { ?>
            <li>
            <a href="#>
            <?php echo $row['achternaam'].", ".strtoupper($row['voorletters'])." ".$row['tussenvoegsel']." (".$row['voornaam'].")";?>
            </a>
            </li>
        <?php }; ?>
</ul>
```

As you can see the anchor tag is just "#", but the goal is to jump to a new "page" (using the jQTouch framework, as this is intended for an iPhone/iPod) and pass on something that is unique to the clicked on dynamically generated item, so that the next "page" knows what to work with.

By the way, the table does have a primary key ($row['id']), so maybe someone knows how to make use of that...?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQtouch pages can all be loaded with a single HTTP GET and the information can be passed to the  jQTouch page via jquery/javascript (the page itself hasn't refreshed, only the jQTouch page has changed).

Let's assume the id of one of your pages is 'info' and you retrieve that from your sql query.

```
<body>
<div id="about">
<ul class="rounded plastic">
        <?php 
            $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempCursist WHERE achternaam BETWEEN 'a%' AND 'e%' ORDER BY achternaam, voorletters");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#<?php echo $row['id']; // this will show the info 'page' aka div based on what we assumed above ?>">
                <?php echo $row['achternaam'].", ".strtoupper($row['voorletters'])." ".$row['tussenvoegsel']." (".$row['voornaam'].")";?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="info">
    <!-- This will be shown after the 'a' tag is clicked with id of info -->
</div>
</body>
```

Don't forget the # in the href. You can use jQuery to find whatever information you need on the jQTouch page that is shown now. The actual page hasn't refreshed.

Note: info should NOT be used as an id in your database.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you so much for taking the time and effort. It works, however, it would mean I'd have to make a div "page" for every record, right?

Comment: each div would be a new page in jQTouch. You would view that page by clicking an <a> tag with an href pointing to the id of the div you'd like shown. So, if you want each record to be its own page then, yes, separate out the records with divs instead of a <ul>.

Comment: Thank you again! I think I mean something else though. I would like to pass on a variable to the next page, which has a value that is representative of the list element one has tapped on, so that the next page knows which list element was tapped on (and work with that). Since every list element is mysql generated, I could use my primary key field value for that somehow. Question is, after one tapped on an element, how does it pass that to the next page. If I use a form, it has to load another document entirely, right? If so, I would then "break out" its full screen mode, right?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, no need to bother! I switched to jQuery Mobile and this is working perfectly for me - in this case better than jQTouch. Many thanks for your help! Cheers.